# Using Selenium RC's -singlewindow option makes things faster but breaks my tests

Tags: selenium-rc

I recently read on here that using the -singlewindow option for Selenium RC would make my tests run faster... I tried this and for some reason it is giving me this error:

14:47:04.801 INFO - Got result: ERROR: Element css=span.TskPgeSbHdr not found on
 session 6090af8597b74d1cae6b0e7bab77a12f

When I run the same test using multi-window mode, it passes.

Can someone please help me understand this?